# Is XmlWriterSettings.DoNotEscapeUriAttributes available in VB.Net 4.0?

Tags: xml, vb.net, .net-4.0

As the title says. My colleague who is using C#.Net Framework 4.5 can set the property fine, but for me in VB.Net 4.0 I get:

**"'DoNotEscapeUriAttributes' is not a member of 'System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings'".**

MSDN says this should be "Available since 2.0", and lists it under VB so as far as I can tell, it should be there? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.donotescapeuriattributes(v=vs.110).aspx

The code I'm using:

```
Dim XMLSettings As XmlWriterSettings = New XmlWriterSettings With
{
.Indent = False,
.DoNotEscapeUriAttributes = True,
.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None,
.OmitXmlDeclaration = True
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't find the property on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings%28v=vs.100%29.aspx so it does not seem to be supported in the .NET framework 4.0.

Comment: Yeah I thought I couldn't find it there either. Seems it's contradictory then between pages.